# WooCommerce - add a missing event to content-product.php quantity

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, onchange, cart

I need to add an event to the quantity selector on the cross-sells on my cart since there bizarrely seems to be no onchange event there.

Normally this would be easy but with WP and WC it's all shortcodes etc so impossible to find the actual place where I can a) correct this and b) not have it overwritten every update, especially since every qty selector should change the data-quantity by default.

cross-sells.php just gives me wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ) which just leads me on to content-product.php which just gives me a load of do_actions.

Specifically, I'd like to correct an error where my content-product.php doesn't seem to have quantity event triggers (ie it doesn't change the data-quantity), but ideally, I'd like to know how I edit any section I want, even if only to improve the awful layout of WC.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for some hook like this if am not wrong.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_item_quantity_update', 'limit_cart_item_quantity', 20, 4 );
function limit_cart_item_quantity( $cart_item_key, $quantity, $old_quantity, $cart ){
    if( ! is_cart() ) return; // At Cart page

    // Limit quantity
    $limit = 5;

    if( $quantity > $limit ){

        $cart->cart_contents[ $cart_item_key ]['quantity'] = $limit;

        wc_add_notice( __('Quantity limit reached for this item'), 'notice' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @mujuonly - i think it's more a jQuery function I need as need to trigger an onchange event on a cross-sell product